# The Expo react native App stops after launch in the Real device

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

I just built the react native APK with Expo, but after installation on my Real device when I launch the App it displays then stops. Can someone please help me?

I've run through the project with Expo go, and everything works perfectly with no errors or warnings.

The application should launch without stopping automatically.